# jQuery and testing React components

Tags: jquery, reactjs, testing

I use jquery and bootstrap so inside my webpack I load them like this

```
module.exports = {
...
entry: {
    bundle: [
      'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'script-loader!tether/dist/js/tether.min.js',
      'script-loader!bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      './app.js'
    ]
  },
...
```

With this I can use jquery inside my code like so

```
console.log('input count', $('input').length)
```

$ is defined and I dont need to require anything else. The problem is with testing. My tests are outside the webpack. I use tape, enzyme, sinon and when I try to test this code or any code that has $ inside i get warning $ is not defined. I tried requiring jquery inside the test  and some other stuff but nothing works except putting this at the top of every file(not test) where I use jquery and then testing it.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I don't like this, importing it again after it is already available. How do I test the code that has jquery/$

Comment: What test framework are you using? I recommend using Jest with webpack, since it can transpile source files without depending on your webpack bundle (for file watching and convenience) and it supports declaring loads for things like CSS imports that would otherwise break the runtime.

Comment: For testing I use babel-tape-runner, jsdom, tape, enzyme and sinon. Yes, I will  sure try Jest next time but for this project i must figure it out using this.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, most test frameworks (other than Jest) recommend running webpack before your tests and requiring the bundle, not the original source files, in your test code.

Comment: No idea how I would do that. I know with karma that I can use webpack but with this stack for testing that I am using don't know where I would define that.

Comment: Why are you including these into the bundle like that? It would be easier to import your libraries directly in the source so your test bundle could also see them.